# Activity Separation field- set an option as default

Tags: activities

[image: Activty Separation field]When you record an activity with multiple target contacts, the Activity Separation option appears. When it first shows it is not immediately obvious that this is a required field.

One of our clients regularly records activities with multiple targets, and by and large only want to record one activity for all.

Would it be possible to set one activity for all- as the default option for this field? And if so, where would I do that?

Also. What are the potential drawbacks of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The change was introduced at https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21419, and it gives the reasoning. As with a lot of things probably 50% of people would disagree.

If you want a quick hack (which would get overriden on upgrade though):
Change line 137 in CRM/Activity/Form/Activity.php from

`protected $supportsActivitySeparation = TRUE;`

to

`protected $supportsActivitySeparation = FALSE;`

Comment: Thank you! I've updated the client and will let them make the call. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some jQuery via an extension to select the default value.

Comment: When you say "you". That's a general "you", I take it.